# Make Linux Mint appear as ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, software-installation

I am trying to install Cloudera Manager 5.x on Linux Mint 17.1 (based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

## Install Commands Used

```
chmod u+x cloudera-manager-installer.bin

sudo ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin
```

## Error

[image]

How can I make Linux Mint appear as Ubuntu to let it install on my system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the installer is checking `/etc/lsb-release`. In Linux Mint, the same file for the Ubuntu version it was derived is under `/etc/upstream-release/lsb-release`. To fool the installer, just replace the former with the latter (although you probably want to back up the file first). In a command terminal you can do:

```
sudo mv /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release.original
sudo cp /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release
```

At some point after your install is done, you can restore the original with:

```
sudo mv /etc/lsb-release.original /etc/lsb-release
```

Comment: Thanks.... your trick worked....although the proper name for the upsteram folder is `upstream-release`

Comment: @Ankesh, oops. Updated.

Comment: Ummm... Is it just me or is this a horrible hack? You've essentially tricked it into running an application that's not supported. That could go wrong in all sorts of ways.

Comment: @David, unlikely. If you look at what Linux Mint actually provides,  it is mostly cosmetic. The underlying system is still Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to change it just for current session with an environment variable:

```
$ lsb_release -cs
linuxmint

$ export LSB_ETC_LSB_RELEASE=/etc/upstream-release/lsb-release

$ lsb_release -cs
xenial
```

[source](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/02/21/linux-change-reference-file-of-lsb-release-from-etc-lsb-release/)

Comment: This approach, setting an environment variable, seems more appropriate and less involved than the accepted answer. It is also less prone to human error than the accepted answer. The installer just needs to know the Ubuntu version you're running, and this environment variable ensures that the installer gets that information.